# How should I approach this "ant deploy" error("unable to add listener...")?

Tags: ant, glassfish, build-process, listener

Here's my error, in picture format in case it's easier to read:

[image]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/iuE8f.png

I appreciate any tips or advice. Here's the text of the error(by the way, ignore the first 4 comments below this):

```
C:\LatestPS\trunk\ws\apps\petstore>ant deploy
Buildfile: C:\LatestPS\trunk\ws\apps\petstore\build.xml

check:

tools:

-pre-deploy:

deploy:
     [exec] remote failure: Error occurred during deployment: Exception while lo
ading the app : java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start:
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java
.lang.IllegalArgumentException: PWC1430: Unable to add listener of type: com.sun
.javaee.blueprints.petstore.model.CatalogFacade, because it does not implement a
ny of the required ServletContextListener, ServletContextAttributeListener, Serv
letRequestListener, ServletRequestAttributeListener, HttpSessionListener, or Htt
pSessionAttributeListener interfaces. Please see server.log for more details.
     [exec] Command deploy failed.

BUILD FAILED
C:\LatestPS\trunk\ws\bp-project\app-server-ant.xml:379: exec returned: 1
```

A meaty stack trace, but here goes:

```
[#|2011-09-19T14:18:13.160-0500|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.1|org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase|_ThreadID=18;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|ContainerBase.addChild: start: 
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: PWC1430: Unable to add listener of type: com.sun.javaee.blueprints.petstore.model.CatalogFacade, because it does not implement any of the required ServletContextListener, ServletContextAttributeListener, ServletRequestListener, ServletRequestAttributeListener, HttpSessionListener, or HttpSessionAttributeListener interfaces
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:5332)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.start(WebModule.java:498)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:917)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:733)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:2000)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:1651)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication.start(WebApplication.java:109)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:130)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.start(ModuleInfo.java:269)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.start(ApplicationInfo.java:294)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:462)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:240)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:382)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$1.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:355)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:370)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1064)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1200(CommandRunnerImpl.java:96)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1244)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1232)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.service(AdminAdapter.java:209)
    at com.sun.grizzly.tcp.http11.GrizzlyAdapter.service(GrizzlyAdapter.java:168)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.HK2Dispatcher.dispath(HK2Dispatcher.java:117)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:238)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:828)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:725)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1019)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:225)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: PWC1430: Unable to add listener of type: com.sun.javaee.blueprints.petstore.model.CatalogFacade, because it does not implement any of the required ServletContextListener, ServletContextAttributeListener, ServletRequestListener, ServletRequestAttributeListener, HttpSessionListener, or HttpSessionAttributeListener interfaces
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.addListener(StandardContext.java:2743)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.addApplicationListener(StandardContext.java:1966)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.TomcatDeploymentConfig.configureApplicationListener(TomcatDeploymentConfig.java:235)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.TomcatDeploymentConfig.configureWebModule(TomcatDeploymentConfig.java:94)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModuleContextConfig.start(WebModuleContextConfig.java:274)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModuleContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(WebModuleContextConfig.java:172)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:149)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:5329)
    ... 38 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: PWC1430: Unable to add listener of type: com.sun.javaee.blueprints.petstore.model.CatalogFacade, because it does not implement any of the required ServletContextListener, ServletContextAttributeListener, ServletRequestListener, ServletRequestAttributeListener, HttpSessionListener, or HttpSessionAttributeListener interfaces
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.createListener(StandardContext.java:2846)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadListener(StandardContext.java:4806)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.loadListener(WebModule.java:1599)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.addListener(StandardContext.java:2740)
    ... 45 more
|#]

[#|2011-09-19T14:18:13.163-0500|WARNING|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.container.web.com.sun.enterprise.web|_ThreadID=18;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: PWC1430: Unable to add listener of type: com.sun.javaee.blueprints.petstore.model.CatalogFacade, because it does not implement any of the required ServletContextListener, ServletContextAttributeListener, ServletRequestListener, ServletRequestAttributeListener, HttpSessionListener, or HttpSessionAttributeListener interfaces
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: PWC1430: Unable to add listener of type: com.sun.javaee.blueprints.petstore.model.CatalogFacade, because it does not implement any of the required ServletContextListener, ServletContextAttributeListener, ServletRequestListener, ServletRequestAttributeListener, HttpSessionListener, or HttpSessionAttributeListener interfaces
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:921)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:733)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:2000)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:1651)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication.start(WebApplication.java:109)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:130)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.start(ModuleInfo.java:269)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.start(ApplicationInfo.java:294)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:462)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:240)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:382)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$1.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:355)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:370)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1064)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1200(CommandRunnerImpl.java:96)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1244)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1232)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.service(AdminAdapter.java:209)
    at com.sun.grizzly.tcp.http11.GrizzlyAdapter.service(GrizzlyAdapter.java:168)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.HK2Dispatcher.dispath(HK2Dispatcher.java:117)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:238)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:828)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:725)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1019)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:225)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
|#]

[#|2011-09-19T14:18:13.166-0500|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.tools.admin.org.glassfish.deployment.admin|_ThreadID=18;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Exception while invoking class com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication start method
java.lang.Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: PWC1430: Unable to add listener of type: com.sun.javaee.blueprints.petstore.model.CatalogFacade, because it does not implement any of the required ServletContextListener, ServletContextAttributeListener, ServletRequestListener, ServletRequestAttributeListener, HttpSessionListener, or HttpSessionAttributeListener interfaces
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication.start(WebApplication.java:138)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:130)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.start(ModuleInfo.java:269)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.start(ApplicationInfo.java:294)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:462)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:240)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:382)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$1.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:355)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:370)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1064)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1200(CommandRunnerImpl.java:96)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1244)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1232)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.service(AdminAdapter.java:209)
    at com.sun.grizzly.tcp.http11.GrizzlyAdapter.service(GrizzlyAdapter.java:168)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.HK2Dispatcher.dispath(HK2Dispatcher.java:117)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:238)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:828)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:725)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1019)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:225)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
|#]

[#|2011-09-19T14:18:13.168-0500|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.core.com.sun.enterprise.v3.server|_ThreadID=18;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Exception while loading the app|#]

[#|2011-09-19T14:18:13.207-0500|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.tools.admin.org.glassfish.deployment.admin|_ThreadID=18;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Exception while loading the app : java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: PWC1430: Unable to add listener of type: com.sun.javaee.blueprints.petstore.model.CatalogFacade, because it does not implement any of the required ServletContextListener, ServletContextAttributeListener, ServletRequestListener, ServletRequestAttributeListener, HttpSessionListener, or HttpSessionAttributeListener interfaces|#]
```

Thank You Very Much

Comment: The `[exec]` is from an `<exec>` task which is an **external** command your Ant script is calling. This isn't an Ant error, but an error in the external command. Please update your question with the full `<exec>` task and we can tell you what the command Ant is trying to execute. And possibly, we can help you with the error. It appears to be an error in attempting to deploy to a Tomcat server. "Petstore" is a name of an app that comes with the Jave Development Kit.

Comment: Hi David, I did find that exec task! here it is above(inside the deploy):

Comment: Ant is working find. Try deploying directly from the command line using the same `asadmin --user admin --passwordfile c:/JEE6SDKglassfish3/glassfish...` command. Make sure the port is open and that you're using the correct password file, etc. I've corrected your tags. This really isn't an _Ant_ issue. This is a _Glassfish_ and using _asadmin_ for deployments.

Comment: Could you please specify the link to the application you're trying to deploy and your environment (i.e. Glassfish version). I know that this application is from Java Blueprints project, but it's actually quite old and it's really important where you took the sources from.

Comment: Sure - 
I am using Java Pet Store version 2.0, which I obtained from here - http://java.net/projects/petstore/sources ,  using SVN: https://svn.java.net/svn/petstore~svn/
My Glassfish version is GlassFish Server 3.1.1  (and I also tried using the the old version:  GlassFish Enterp. Server v2.1.1. , part of  Java Platform, Enterprise Edition 5 SDK Update 8 ). I've been switching back-and-forth between Glassfish 3.1.1 and 2.1.1 .  With version 2.1.1 I've been getting a different error: `deploy:
     [exec] CLI001 Invalid Command, --user.` , then the browser actually opens.. but I get 404 error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just actually built and deployed this project on Glassfish 3.1 without any problems. I just had to tweak some properties, since I was using my own server (not from Java EE SDK) but that shouldn't matter.

So, building and running this project actually requires 3 steps. Let's call the `ws` folder `${samples-root}`. Then you have to:

1. Correctly set properties in `${samples-root}/bp-project/build.properties`
2. Change to `${samples-root}/apps/petstore` and issue `ant setup` from command prompt
3. Issue `ant run` command.

That's it. Now you can open http://localhost:8080/petstore in your web browser and explore this application.

As for your post, I see you issued `ant deploy` command which should be automatically called from `run` target, so you don't have to do that.

Actually there's quite a good tutorial on how to build and run this app included. You can find it in `${samples-root}/apps/petstore/index.html`.

Also I saw from your previous posts that you tried to deploy it manually via admin console. I don't recommend you doing it unless you clearly understand the build process since you might have missed something.

**Important:** before you do anything, don't forget to start glassfish and database server by issuing the following commands from `$GLASSFISH_HOME/bin` (here `$GLASSFISH_HOME` would probably be `glassfish3/glassfish`) `asadmin start-domain`, `asadmin start-database`.

Comment: Thank You very much jFrenetic, I will work on this right now. I think the issue must be in my build.properties.  For `# machine name (or the IP address) where the applications will be deployed.` I put the IP address there, rather than localhost.  I am really indebted to you. Thanks so much!

Comment: By the way, I'm a little bit lost when you say `was using my own server (not from Java EE SDK) but that shouldn't matter` --> do you mean like Tomcat or a similar program?

Comment: Hey, no problem. Just please don't repost the same question as it irritates many folks :)

Comment: No, like I said in the first sentence, I was using Glassfish 3.1, but I already had it installed, so I just changed the build.properties accordingly to point to different javaee.home.

Comment: I've done exactly as you've said... but I'm getting that same error. So I will dig into the code a bit - the `CatalogFacade` class seems to be an issue. I dunno what's the deal.  May I ask which version of Java are you using? I have windows 7 and java 1.6.0_20.  I'm gonna see what I can do.  Many thanks!

Comment: Suppose that the problem is this listener issue, that says: `java
.lang.IllegalArgumentException: PWC1430: Unable to add listener of type: com.sun
.javaee.blueprints.petstore.model.CatalogFacade, because it does not implement any of the required ServletContextListener, ServletContextAttributeListener, ServletRequestListener....`   if that is the issue, do you have any hints about what to do? I do believe this is my issue.   I guess I'll start examining server log and googling alot.

Comment: In my build.properties file there were proxy settings that I left blank. I don't think this matters though, right?

Comment: Your version of jdk is fine. In most cases it's enough to have 5 or higher. There shouldn't be any problem with the listener, since these are the blueprints which are aimed to show how to write the code properly. Proxy settings are obviously needed if you're behind the proxy. When running ant `setup` and `run` I would redirect the output to another file and then examine all the possible errors during the build.

Comment: Thanks you so much. Hmm yes I need to find out the proxy settings too. And Excellent idea to redirect the output while running ant setup/run .  I don't mind burnin the midnight oil a little more and figuring this out.

Comment: Are you sure you need proxy? Like do you have proxy settings in your browser or elsewhere on the system? And ant output should be very carefully analyzed, because if the error happens in the very beginning it doesn't make sense to go further.